# Hide Footer When Keyboard Appear Mobile Web Muse UI

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I use vue.js with muse.ui here, and only use javascript and css without jquery library.
Now footer position always on the top of keyboard everytime the input field get focus.
is it do(able) to make footer position behind the keyboard everytime input get focus ?

```css
#foot {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <mu-text-field type="text" />
  </div>
</form>
<footer>
  <mu-col class="foot">blablablablablablabla</mu-col>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS you have defined #foot (which is an ID).

In your html "foot" is set as class:
`<mu-col class="foot">blablablablablablabla</mu-col>`

Either "foot" has to be defined as class in CSS or referred to as ID in the 
HTML

```
`<mu-col id="foot">blablablablablablabla</mu-col>`
```

OR

in css define foot as class, that is ,

```
.foot {
...
}
```

Comment: hmm yeap i was just typo when write this question.. but now i can fix it with some js.. thanks :)